# web3.eth.sendTransaction passing paramaters along with mandatory transactionObject

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

Aloha.

Web3 version is 0.20, and, according to documentation:

web3.eth.sendTransaction

web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])

Sends a transaction to the network.
Parameters

```
Object - The transaction object to send:

from: String - The address for the sending account. Uses the web3.eth.defaultAccount property, if not specified.
to: String - (optional) The destination address of the message, left undefined for a contract-creation transaction.
value: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional) The value transferred for the transaction in Wei, also the endowment if it's a contract-creation transaction.
gas: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The amount of gas to use for the transaction (unused gas is refunded).
gasPrice: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The price of gas for this transaction in wei, defaults to the mean network gas price.
data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.
nonce: Number - (optional) Integer of a nonce. This allows to overwrite your own pending transactions that use the same nonce.

Number|String - (optional) If you pass this parameter it will not use the default block set with web3.eth.defaultBlock.
Function - (optional) If you pass a callback the HTTP request is made asynchronous. See this note for details.
```

I have function placeBet() which accepts multiple parameters:

```
function placeBet(uint8 _outcome, uint desiredMatchIndex, uint _amount) public payable{
// find a way to store a bid in order to be easily searchable, in order to easily send money to winners;
    //   require(!roundEnd, "Interactions with contract are locked, be careful next time!");
    //   require(state == State.Active, "Betting is over, game have already started!");
    require(msg.value > 0, "It isn't possible to place a bet without a money ");
     if(!isDuplicate(msg.sender)) addressIndices.push(msg.sender);
     testina(msg.sender, _outcome, desiredMatchIndex);
      existingBets[msg.sender].push(Bet({
          bettor: msg.sender,
        //   name: name,
          amount: _amount,
          bet: desiredMatchIndex,
          outcome: _outcome
      }));
      //emit event, finally;
}
```

, so my question is how should I include needed additional parameters (outcome, desiredMatchIndex, amount ) [maybe last one is reduntant ] alongside
*transactionObject* using web3.js?

Thanks : )

Comment: Maybe it's just as in .call function? ( transactionObject, params...)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i am sorry, there was an example in documentation, just not adequately referenced.

```
/ Explicitly sending a transaction to this method
myContractInstance.myMethod.sendTransaction(param1 [, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, callback])
```